# Does linux 2.6.32 have 'at' command, can I add this command into it?

Tags: linux, command-line

I am trying to run 'at' command to execute a shell at morning. But I met this on the remote host

```
bash: at: command not found
```

I runed $PATH, it shows

```
bash: /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:
```

As I ran the 'at' command well at my Ubuntu14.04, which has Linux 3.13 on it, so I ran uname -r on the remote host, and it shows

```
2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64
```

What's the problem that I can't run 'at' command on the remote host, how to fix it?

- when using 'batch' command, the same 'command not found' prompt out

Comment: No, the kernel doesn’t have an `at` command. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install the `at` command. It is not part of the standard packages of most distributions.

On `Debian` and it's derivates its:

```
sudo apt-get install at
```

On `Redhat` based systems its:

```
sudo yum install at
```

On `Redhat` based systems it appeared that the `at` daemon `atd`, which is required to schedule and execute actions, will getting started after package installation. You need to perform the following commands:

Start daemon:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/atd start
```

Make sure it gets started during next reboot:

```
sudo /sbin/chkconfig --add atd
sudo /sbin/chkconfig atd on
```

Comment: you saved my life, hero

Comment: after I do this, when I run the at command again. It shows "Can't open /var/run/atd.pid to signal atd. No atd running?"

Comment: Which system are you using?

Comment: I tried sudo yum install atd, it says 'No package atd available.'

Comment: I guess the remote host is using centos. 'redhat' stuff

Comment: And it could be debian, I'm googleing how to check it. But it's absolutely not ubuntu.

Comment: You need to start the daemon: `/etc/init.d/atd start`

Comment: It's debian jessie/sid

Comment: why when I did it, it says job4 start? this atd stuff is no harming to the remote host, right?

Comment: And by the way, hero. After I execute an 'at' command, if I close the ssh connection, and if the remote host keep on running. It will execute that 'at' command at the target time, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The remote system (I assume this is the system where `at` should run?) can only have `apt` (Debian) or `yum` (Redhat).